# Categorical Complications for DNNRegressor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

I am working with a set of data like the following

[ Code1, Code2, Code3, CodeGroup ]
[ J21  , K11  , L45  , 207       ]
[ E45  , R72  , M09  , 113       ]
[ K11  , J21  , Z12  , 207       ]

I am hoping to create a NN that will start to pick up on patterns like seeing J21 and K11 in the same row and predict a group code of 207.

I know one complication is the fact that I have strings instead of numbers. Here are a few options I have tried to resolve that

- tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast -> takes an String Tensor and outputs an Int64 Tensor
- pd.get_dummies() -> which will resolve ['j21', 'K11', 'L45'] to [ [1, 0, 0], ..]
- CategoricalProcessor from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.preprocessing.categorical.CategoricalProcessor but not sure how to incorporate this

I also believe that since these codes can be in different columns that it may cause an issue in training as well. In the example above you can see 'J21' in both Code1 and Code2  columns. Perhaps I need to lay the data out differently?!?

Here is a [snippet of my code](https://gist.github.com/afreeland/889e27b19765a084f1b651e31757b10a), that I managed to get working...and by working I mean executing with the worse accuracy in existence -_-

If anyone has any input on how to go about solving this I would so appreciate it. Went through a TON of tutorials successfully but got smacked back to reality on when attempting on my own :(